# How to include apt in sudoers without password

Tags: apt, sudo, apt-fast

I want to authorize user **daniel** to use **apt** with any arguments without enter the password. **NOT apt-get or aptitude**. The **APT** command:

- sudo apt update
- sudo apt dist-upgrade
- sudo apt list -a <match>
- sudo apt search <match>
- sudo apt install <match>
- sudo apt purge <match>
- sudo apt <anything>

I am trying with a custom `/etc/sudoers.d/daniel` and my sudoers file is unchanged and has the lines:

```
# See sudoers(5) for more information on "@include" directives:
@includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

My `/etc/sudoers.d/daniel`:

```
# Allow daniel to execute apt without password
daniel ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/apt
```

But it's not working. I tried also:

```
daniel ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/apt *
```

But no success.

But it works for **apt-fast**...

```
daniel ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/apt-fast
```

Comment: Read `man sudoers`.

Comment: I read. The solution seems to be: `daniel ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:^/usr/bin/apt.*$`. But did not test it yet, i am at phone.

Comment: No, doesn't work. But `/usr/bin/apt*` works for apt-get and apttude.

Comment: Avoid using the wildcard, `/usr/bin/apt`. In `man sudoers`, did you read down to the end?

Comment: If `daniel ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt` i can execute **apt update** without password, but not **sudo apt update**. Weird. Yes i did read down to the end. What i am missing? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have found a solution to my own question.

Usually `$ sudo apt (...)` or just `$ apt (...)` need a password to be executed, as well as **apt-get**, **aptitude** and **apt-fast** (the latter a download accelerator).

With this solution is possible to execute any of them with **sudo** without password, BUT **apt** (not apt-get), to be executed without password, must not be executed with sudo (as in `$ sudo apt update`, but just `$ apt update` instead).

```
username ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt, /usr/bin/apt-get,\
                         /usr/bin/aptitude, /usr/bin/apt-fast
```